# Laravel 7.x Eloquent recursive relationship - get all ids

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a project where the `customers` table self references via a `parent_id`. The top customer is the app, then customers below are direct customers of the app, and customers below them are their customers.

My `Customer` model relationships are:

```
/**
 * Client Parent
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsTo
 */
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

/**
 * Client Children
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasMany
 */
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

/**
 * Client's All Children
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasMany
 */
public function allChildren()
{
    return $this->children()->with('children');
}
```

I then, in my `Controller` I get all children like this:

```
 // Get all children customers of the user's customer
 $customerTree = $customer->allChildren;

 $customerIdsInTree = $customerTree->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

The `$customerIdsInTree` contains all `id` for the direct descendants of the current customer, but not their children. I can see the children as relations loaded for each descendant if I `dd($customerTree)`.

How do I pluck all the `id` from the tree when the second level customers are in their respective relation of the direct descendant customer?

Or differently, how do I flatten the collection so the parent and children rows are all in the same collection?

Comment: For flattening the collection, you may want to look into [mapWithKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-mapwithkeys)

Comment: You only want to pluck the id right? Maybe just make a simple query like $customersId = Customer::wherNotNull('parent_id')->pluck('id')

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cursive function to get all the children

```
    public function allChildren ()
    {
        $children_customers = new Collection();

        foreach ($this->children as $child_customer) {
            $children_customers->push($child_customer);
            $children_customers = $children_customers->merge($child_customer->getAllChildren());
        }

        return $children_customers;
    }
```

Then in your Controller, you just have to pluck the `ids`

```
 $customerIdsInTree = $customer->getAllChildren()->pluck('id');
```